# JS Wait for few events in a function to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a function which uploads images and displays it on the page. How should I do to wait for the function to complete?

```
$("#images").change(function(){
        updateArray(this);
        addImages();
    });

function updateArray(inp)
    {
        for(var i=0,file; file = inp.files[i]; i++)
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (evt)
            {
                images[images.length] = evt.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

I want to call addImages() after all events in updateArray() are completed

Comment: What's `updateArray`?  Is it synchronous?  Asynchronous?  We can't help you without the definition of the `updateArray` function.

Comment: can you show us the code of the updateArray-Function? In common you achieve this with callbacks in JS.

Comment: P.S. Why are you doing `images[images.length] = ...;`?  Just do `images.push(evt.target.result);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use jQuery's [deferred/promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) here.  This will allow you to wait until *each* `onload` is complete, and then trigger a callback.

Here's an example:

```
function updateArray(inp)
{
    var promises = [];
    for(var i=0,file; file = inp.files[i]; i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader(),
            d = new $.Deferred();

        promises.push(d);
        // Make sure we "capture" the correct 'd'
        (function(d){
            reader.onload = function (evt)
            {
                images.push(evt.target.result);
                d.resolve();
            }
        }(d));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    return $.when.apply($, promises);
}
```

This will create a new deferred object for each `FileReader`.  When each one finishes, its respective deferred will be resolved.  The `$.when` is used to combine all of the deferreds into one.  So, in your `.change()`, you can simply do this:

```
$("#images").change(function(){
    updateArray(this).done(function(){
        addImages();
    });
});
```

P.S. You can also pass parameters to `resolve()` to be used in the `.done()` callback.  So, instead of appending to the `images` array, you can do `d.resolve(evt.target.result);`.

```
(function(d){
    reader.onload = function (evt)
    {
        d.resolve(evt.target.result);
    }
}(d));
```

Then in `.done()`, you can do:

```
$("#images").change(function(){
    updateArray(this).done(function(){
        // Each '.resolve' added a new parameter to here, let's get them all
        images = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
        addImages();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know what `images` is supposed to be, but I'd suggest to discard it and use `d.resolve(evt.target.result)` instead - getting the `images` as the result of the returned promise.

Comment: @Bergi: Not a bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you can approach this, however if you're using jQuery (which you appear to be) I'd recommend looking into promises (see: http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

They are a more modern paradigm for deferred callbacks which have some semantic processing for executing functions based on successful completion, failure, and those which will always process.